# When using the useEffect hook, the method of using a dependency array is confusing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been studying react hook lately. I found the following in the book I saw.

It is said that the `fetchAndSetUser` function is updated only when the `userId` is changed using the `useCallback` hook.

```
function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const fetchAndSetUser = useCallback(
    async needDetail => {
      const data = await fetchUser(userId, needDetail);
      setUser(data);
    },
    [userId]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAndSetUser(false);
  } , [fetchAndSetUser]);
// ...
```

However, if the `fetchAndSetUser` function is updated only when the userId is changed using the `useCallback` hook, I wonder what the difference is from just putting the `userId` in the dependency array in the `useEffect` hook. (There is a code below.)

```
function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const fetchAndSetUser = async ( needDetail ) => {
    const data = await fetchUser(userId, needDetail);
    setUser(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAndSetUser(false);
  } , [userId]);
// ...
```

I wonder if the two codes are the same or if they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I think both codes would achieve the same result, there is a small difference.

If you wanted to pass that fetchAndSetUser (with no useCallback) function to the children, any time Profile component updated it would also update the children.

You can always combine all with:

```
function Profile({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const fetchAndSetUser = useCallback(async ( needDetail ) => {
    const data = await fetchUser(userId, needDetail);
    setUser(data);
  }, [userId]);
useEffect(() => {
  fetchAndSetUser(false);
} , [userId]);
```

Comment: I understood. Thank you for your answer!